# How to form gerunds in German?

Tags: gerund

I only know how to do one-word gerunds e.g. das Atmen, das Singen

However, I commonly use gerunds that exist as a phrase. For example, 'I am interested in becoming a doctor' as well as longer and more complicated ones.

I want to know how you'd form these in German.

Comment: You don't use gerunds for this in German. "Ich bin daran interessiert Arzt zu werden."

Comment: How would I be able to recognise this with other similar sentences?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct equivalent of the English gerund in German.

Some aspects of the English gerund can be replicated in German with a substantiated infinitive as you mentioned in the first part of your question, some other aspects with an infinitive subclause with "zu".

> Breathing is one of our most common activities
>
> Atmen ist eine unsrer wichtigsten Handlungen
>
> I started reading the newspaper
>
> Ich fing an, die Zeitung zu lesen

Comment: Is there any way in which much more complicated gerunds can exist?

Comment: @TomEdwards What do you mean with "more complicated" - Even more complicated examples will more or less boil down to the two basic forms above.

Comment: I was just worried in case there are problems this may cause when trying to use a gerund, which I'd expect to arise with a longer, phrase-like gerund.

Comment: Please give an English example in your original question.

Comment: Well, another possibility to form a gerund in German, which works almost anytime, is to construct someting with "tun". So instead of "Er liest Zeitung" one can say "Er tut Zeitung lesen", or istead of "Ich lese Zeitung" - "Ich tu' Zeitung lesen". But this is really bad German, and I can only recommend not to use this form.